# Can anyone tell the difference in material setup for a chocolate solid and a chocolate liquid

Tags: materials

I make chocolate using mix shader connected in a diffuse and glossy and a fresnel in the factor input.But that looks like a molten chocolate How can we make it look like solid chocolate

Comment: Could you post desired example of what you want? There are several different solid chocolates out there.

Comment: The only way to answer this is if you show what you have done so far. We don't even know what render engine you are using, solutions for blender internal are going to be different than for cycles. Also please show a reference image of what you want it to look like.

Comment: By pure speculation, I would think you want to turn up the roughness. This should make it less reflective and make it look more like solid chocolate. But like others have said, can't really help without references and screenshots.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Roughness of the material is the only difference. Here I use the same material but only slightly change the roughness: [image]